Does mongo shell support transactions?
I have tried running a insertMany/insertOne statement with transaction, but the mongo shell goes into a loading state indefinitely
Here's what I tried:
> use test;
> const session = db.getMongo().startSession();
> session.startTransaction();
> const doc = {name: "test", value: 1};
> db.myCollectionName.insertOne(doc, {session})

After this, it just stays on loading
enter image description here
Anyone can help me out ? I have a very specific usecase to use mongo shell only. I know this can be achieved very easily using Node/Py

I'm not sure if you actually opened the image before commenting.
The image is the same as what I've added in text.

Well the issue is that the command is just stuck at loading. It keeps loading indefinitely. Which I have already mentioned in the description. Maybe that is not enough for you to understand the issue, but that's all I've got at the moment.

Did you try db.getMongo().getDB(<database>)?

@WernfriedDomscheit Do you mean db.getMongo().getDB(<database_name>).one.insertOne(doc, {session})  ? I tried this, still in the same situation.

It keeps loading indefinitely - it's unlikely like you said and the transaction itself mostlikely unrelated to your question. Do you have any issues without transaction? Can you use try/catch and see whether any error is thrown in your initial code?

You need to get the database from the session.
Mongosh is slightly different from node/py driver and uses shell helpers with their own syntax flavour.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/ accepts only writeConcern options in the second parameter and ignores everything else.
Your session doesn't apply there, so it tries to write outside the transaction.
Use session.getDatabase() instead:
use test;
const session = db.getMongo().startSession();
col = session.getDatabase(db.getName()).myCollectionName;  
session.startTransaction();
const doc = {name: "test", value: 1};
col.insertOne(doc, {session})
session.commitTransaction();
session.endSession();

Now a word of warning - you learned from experience how an open transaction affects other operations. There is no workaround. They are just not designed to stay open for long time. Think again if you want to do it manually via shell.

Thank you . This is what I was looking for.

I need to combine collections from different databases. And I have to do it via mongo shell.
I wanted to use a transaction so that if there are any issues and it fails, all the changes can be rolledback.

Sure, it does make sense. Just keep in mind that you block write operations while transaction is open. You are buying a luxury to roll back if anything goes wrong for the cost of making wrong to all other clients connected to the database. It might be ok in your case tho. Just be aware of the cost.

Yup, will keep that in mind. Thanks !
